# Roll-up summary field of formula fields that returns currency

Tags: custom-object, formula-field, roll-up-summary

Documentation it shows that SUM is only available for some types of data. Currency is one of them.
I can't use my formula field to do the SUM of all of them.
That's the structure of my child object.
[image: That's the structure of my child object.]

This is how it shows to me when I try to sum the "Interes" field.

[image]

Can anyone bring me a hand with this?

Regards

Comment: Formula fields cannot be rolled up if they reference data on other SObjects (known as a "cross-object" formula field) either directly or indirectly. Please [edit] your question to show us the formula for your `Interes__c` field.

Comment: @DerekF you pointed it in the eye. That formula field was using a value from it's father. I'll talk to the team to define the "interest" rate as a variable. Thank you for that comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula fields can only be rolled up (by a standard rollup summary field) when it *only* references data on the SObject it is defined on. So if you have a formula field on `Opportunity`, it can only use `Opportunity` fields.

This goes for both direct and indirect references. If you have another formula field which references data on another SObject (making it a "cross-object formula"), using that other formula field in the formula field you're currently working on still counts as "references data on another SObject".

If you can restructure your formula so that it only references data on its host SObject, then you would be able to select it on the rollup summary screen.

If you can't restructure the formula, there's still hope. In that situation, you could use a Flow to copy the value of a cross-object formula field into a new (non-formula, and appropriately typed) field. That's sufficient to make that related data part of the host SObject proper, and you'd be able to then use that new field in your formula. The only downsides are:

- A change to the data on the other referenced SObject will not cause an update to "downstream" SObjects (unless you have a trigger or something)
- It requires you to add an extra field (and manage the FLS, which does not get deployed along with the field)